# How to filter databases on its Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, vb.net, filter

I need to search for data and show it on the page. I want a code in the index to be something similar to this

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) Then
   students = students.Where(Function(s) s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) _
   Or s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()))
```

but instead of string I am searching for ID which is integer. How can I do that?

I am creating a asp.net mvc web application using vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an integer you may just check for equality.

```
students = students.Where(Function(s) s.Id = searchId)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day. I have no idea why the site does not allow me to accept the answer